# Can't fix error "failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections"

Tags: php, file-upload

(Note to whoever marked it as duplicate, I did not know it was the path that was causing the error, the other questions was specific to the path causing the error, my question was not. Since I had no idea it was the path that was causing the error, there was no way for me to solve my problem with that other question)

Hello I have a php project and I have been trying to figure out an image upload tutorial for w3 and have been unable to get rid of errors. I have searched the errors and the tutorial does what any solution suggests so I think Im just missing something obvious, can someone please help.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$target_dir = "http://myDomainName.com/SchoolStore/Images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        //echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading ". $target_file;
    }
}
?>
```

Errors:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://myDomainName.com/SchoolStore/Images/Screen Shot 2015-11-28 at 5.30.11 PM.png): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home1/tooneate/public_html/SchoolStore/upload.php on line 43

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/var/tmp/phpc2F3xS' to 'http://myDomainName.com/SchoolStore/Images/Screen Shot 2015-11-28 at 5.30.11 PM.png' in /home1/tooneate/public_html/SchoolStore/upload.php on line 43
Sorry, there was an error uploading http://myDomainName.com/SchoolStore/Images/Screen Shot 2015-11-28 at 5.30.11 PM.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing

`$target_dir = "http://myDomainName.com/SchoolStore/Images/";` 
you need to use the server path to

`/SchoolStore/Images/` (e.g. `/home/content/proj/SchoolStore/Images/`).

You cannot open a file via HTTP. Instead you need to open it using the local path.

Comment: This confused me briefly on how to get the correct path, but for future reference to anyone looking at this question to get the correct path I had to log into my hosting service and look at my file management hierarchy tree, Thanks!